# Visual Studio error: There was a conflict between two files

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I have an UWP app in the Windows Store, and I was now preparing an update and when I do: Project> Store> Create App Packages and when it starts the process appear 13 warnings and are almost all the same. The warning is this:

There was a conflict between two files. There was a conflict between two references with the same file name between the `"WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.10240.0" and "WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.14393.0"` SDKs. Choosing `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd"` over `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.Networking.Sockets.ControlChannelTriggerContract.winmd"` because it was resolved first.

What error is this? How do I solve it?

I already looked for a resolution and I can not find anything. This error never appeared!

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing 2 different versions of the `WindowsMobile` SDK:

- `Version=10.0.10240.0`
- `Version=10.0.14939.0`

This creates a conflict when building the solution.
Ensure that all your projects reference the same version of the SDK.

Comment: Thank you! But why does this error happen? I did not make any changes, this mistake had never appeared. And how do I solve it?

Comment: @FernandoSousa You probably installed the newest Windows update, Visual Studio update and/or added a new project afterwards? You have to check the `References` node of the projects. There you should be able to see two different versions in those two projects.